# Unit testing code that depends on dart:html

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I'm trying to write unit tests on a piece of code that imports `dart:html` and I ended up having a test class that's using `useHtmlConfiguration();`

Do I really have to do this? Because it seems everytime I run my tests, it runs in a browser, dart2js gets called and it's taking much longer than if I were testing with the dartVM. I tried it with Dartium and it also recompiles.

In fact, the only reason my code uses dart:html is because it's using `HttpRequest` in the package. At the end I might just end up putting an interface in front of the class doing the http request and mocking it, but I was wondering if there were an efficient way of having a good (read quick) feedback loop without having to call dart2js everytime I want to run my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code imports `dart:html` the code and also tests importing this code can only be run in the browser.

I don't know why dart2js is called. You can run tests in Dartium or `content_shell --dump-render-tree` (headless Dartium) as Dart code without transpiling to JS first.

You might prefer using the http package which has some abstraction of HttpRequest which should on client and server (haven't tested it myself this way yet).

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the package `http` however everything client-side related used dart:html, so it's not really better. Also, I tried `content_shell` but is there a utility to parse if my tests went successfully? All I get by calling this is a dump of the DOM (and that's what I expected). I'm currently trying `hop` and `hop_runner`, but it seems to be outdated right now.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is cumbersome. I spent a lot of time to make this usable. 
The Dart team is currently working on improving the unittest package (currently renamed to test) and adding a testrunner which is also capable of running browser tests. I can't tell if browser tests are supported good enough already but I can't take long anymore. They're making lot or progress.

Comment: Still @Günter, what packages do you use to run your tests with content_shell? Doing in manually and interpreting the output every time? I can't seem versions of `hop`/`hop_unittest`/`browser_unittest` that seem to work together.

Comment: I build my own but it's not in a state anyone else can use. I'm pretty sure https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test (version 0.12.0-beta.4) is the way to go. Even when it might not be finished yet, it will be soon the best package for this task. It will replace `unittest` soon and includes a testrunner.